# Select Group on Department

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have data like below. I want to select those Emp_id where only HR is the only DEPT present. From the below, only **100994 and 100998** should be selected.

```
**EMP_ID    DEPT**
100017  FIN
100017  HR
100017  ADMIN
100994  HR
100997  ADMIN
100997  FIN
100998  HR
100999  FIN
```

Comment: What is your table name?

Comment: You can name it TABLE1

Comment: I posted an answer. Please check

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (emp_id, dept) as
  2    (select 100017, 'FIN'   from dual union all
  3     select 100017, 'HR'    from dual union all
  4     select 100017, 'ADMIN' from dual union all
  5     select 100994, 'HR'    from dual union all
  6     select 100997, 'ADMIN' from dual union all
  7     select 100997, 'FIN'   from dual union all
  8     select 100998, 'HR'    from dual union all
  9     select 100999, 'FIN'   from dual
 10    )
 11  select emp_id
 12  from test
 13  group by emp_id
 14  having min(dept) = max(dept)
 15     and min(dept) = 'HR';

    EMP_ID
----------
    100998
    100994

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment to use a subquery to count the records.
If records count for specific id is more than 1 then skip the id.

```
SELECT `emp_id`, `dept` FROM (
    SELECT SUM(1) AS `count`, `emp_id`, `dept`
    FROM `table1`
    GROUP BY `emp_id`
) AS `derived`
WHERE `count` = 1 AND `dept` = 'HR'
```